# Python 3 -Printing to console in spreadsheet format so I can cut and paste columns

Tags: python, csv

As described on the title I would like to print to the console two or more columns of strings so that I can copy and paste into a goog sheet and it will maintain the column separation format(ie one word per cell). I tried printing strings separated by a tab to no avail. I do not want to write to csv with a module.
Thanks

Comment: Could you paste your current work?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Just load csv into pandas dataframe and print it you will get better format

Comment: The problem is with your sheet programs. Both excel and google sheets have text to columns -feature, which can properly sort your text using almost any delimiter you want. In google sheets you can find it from "data:Split text to columns" menu. In excel it's in "data:text to columns"

Comment: @StackingForHeap, thanks, did not know about that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer this question without knowing the exact format of the text you are trying to format. But here is an example of what you can do if your text is stored in a list of lists representing rows of data:

```py
In [9]: def delimited(delimiter, text):
   ...:     for i in text:
   ...:         print(delimiter.join(i))
   ...:

In [10]: foo = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]

In [11]: delimited(' ', foo)
```

Prints:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Now you can paste it that into a Google Sheet and it should automatically detect the line breaks and paste the data into separate rows. Now select the column containing your data, and click on `Data` in the menu bar, followed by `Split Text to Columns...` Google should autodetect the spaces as delimiters and split your data into separate columns. Otherwise, you can even try passing different delimiters into the function above, e.g. comma, semi-colon, etc. and then specifying the delimiter in your Google Sheet after clicking `Split Text to Columns...`

Comment: Thanks Aryan. In this respect you did provide A solution which I am likely to use(formatting in google sheet rather then python). It would be nice to know from the experts if there is indeed a way to do it. I looked into prettyprint but nothing there jumped to focus. I'll wait some time before marking your answer. Thanks.